# Running window.crypto.getRandomValues() from inside a Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm at my wit's end here. Is there any way to do this, knowing that web workers can't access the `window` object? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this, seeing as the Crypto class and methods are "native code", meaning they are implemented at a lower-level in the browser, so we can't extract the code and move it somewhere else. I tried using [Chrome's Transferrable Objects](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast) object gets erased from current context and passed to worker, but that throws an error. I don't think that the crypto api needs to be coupled to the DOM ( WebWorkers won't touch the DOM as it isn't thread-safe ), but I've never implemented crypto before. In Node, we have an async api, so to me, at least, it seems like it should be thread-safe.

http://cl.ly/image/0r0P3m3D2h07 <- Inspection of `window.crypto`

http://cl.ly/image/0G1G0F1Y0d3Z <- Example code for passing crypto to WebWorker throws.

I created a WebWorker script to verify, that maybe, just *maybe*, Chrome and Firefox just had different implementations, and unfortunately, I was mistaken.

I've sent an email to the authors of the [W3C Web Crypto API Proposal](http://www.w3.org/2012/webcrypto/WebCryptoAPI/#Crypto-method-createEncrypter), and you should as well. The draft seems to have a few open issues at this point, so it seems like it could change. Having either an async API or having the `crypto` API being available in Web Workers seems perfectly reasonable to me. Seems like a bad thing to have blocking the main event loop.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but i stumbled accross and things changed. Most browsers do support crypto in webworkers now.

In webworkers you can access `self` which does not contain all of the "window" properties (especially nothing dom-related), but holds API methods like crypto functions.

Therefore you can simply access `self.crypto.getRandomValues()` from within webworker.

I made a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbrosi/yj17gomk/

However please not that calls to webworker and back are also having a small performance impact and most expensive crypto functions (like `crypto.subtle.encrypt` are async and should therefore *not* block your mainthread at all.

Comment: @tigrou yes, it is possible. As all the methods from the main thread are also available in worker thread. Maybe you tested on non-https and non-localhost. Chrome (and others) enable crypto only in secure environments (+localhost as exception)